# Indenting 2nd line of text only

Tags: css, indentation, word-wrap

I have 2 spanned text styles, One overflows onto a 2nd line and I'm trying to figure out how I can indent the 2nd line only. Does anyone have a solution that doesn't require me putting them in their own containers?

[image: I've attached a pic to demonstrate.]

```
<span class="step-a">STEP 3.</span><span class="step-b">This line is ok.</span>
<span class="step-a">STEP 4.</span><span class="step-b">I don't like the way this wraps</span>
<span class="step-a">STEP 5.</span><span class="step-b">This line is ok.</span>

.step-a { display:inline; color:#3498DB; font-size: 14px; text-transform:capitalize; vertical-align:baseline; } 
.step-b { display:inline; color:#8e8e93; font-size: 16px; vertical-align:baseline; padding-left:10px; } 
.step-b:after { content:"\A"; white-space:pre; }
```

Comment: Can I change span to divs?

Comment: why not use a table, or a list (li or ul)?

Comment: @Wietse It's starting to look inevitable..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the css only way([`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/5LLW4/show/)):

```
.step-a {
    float: left;
    display:inline;
    color:#3498DB;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform:capitalize;
    vertical-align:baseline;
}
.step-b {
    color: #8e8e93;
    font-size: 16px;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    padding-left: 10px;
    display: block;
    word-break: break-all;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

here is your solution: http://jsfiddle.net/mYQZp/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <span class="step-a">STEP 3.</span><span class="step-b">This line is ok.</span>
    </div>

    <div>
<span class="step-a">STEP 4.</span><span class="step-b">I don't like the way this wraps</span>
    </div>

    <div>
<span class="step-a">STEP 5.</span><span class="step-b">This line is ok.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.step-a {
    display:block;
    width:50px;
    color:#3498DB;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-top:2px;
    text-transform:capitalize;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    float:left;
}
.step-b {
    display:block;
    width:90px;
    color:#8e8e93;
    font-size: 16px;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    padding-left:10px;
    float:left;
}
.step-b:after {
    content:"\A"; white-space:pre; }

.clear{clear:both; height:1px;}
.container{display: block; width:175px; background:#f2f2f2; padding:10px;}
```

Comment: Looks horrible in chrome.

Comment: Its looking fine in my firefox @rizzledon.

Comment: @MayankTripathi Sorry I meant works in FF but not Safari

Comment: Its looking fine in my Safari also @rizzledon